# jQuery datepicker not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, datepicker

I have a very basic script that sets up datepicker on three of my inputs, this script works **perfect** in all browsers apart from Internet Explorer, I just wondered if anyone knew why. This is *all* of my JavaScript for that page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        CKEDITOR.replace('content');
        $('input.datepicker').datepicker();
        $('input[name="media"]').click(function() {
            $('fieldset.media').toggle('slow');
        });
        $('input[name="digital"]').click(function() {
            $('fieldset.digital').toggle('slow');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The element exists because it works in all other browsers. Firebug (Firefox addon) does not show any errors.

Thanks for any help you can give.

#### EDIT

This is what my script tag for including jQuery looks like.

```
<script src='/assets/javascript/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

#### EDIT 2

It is working completely (including opacity) in IE6 and IE7, IE8 is not working.

Comment: What version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using? Also, what exactly does or doesn't happen in IE?

Comment: What do your `<script>` tags look like, where you include jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, this is in IE 8 with the latest version of jQuery and UI. The script tag is included in my post now. I know that is all in order. Opacity is not working as well as the datepicker.

Comment: You should include the jQuery version number rather than just saying 'the latest version'.  That way it will be more useful when someone views the post in 6 months time.

Comment: Okay then, I have now fixed it (awnser below) but just for the record it was jQuery v1.4.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it by using individual ID's for each of the elements and changing the conditional comment for Blueprint CSS from this

```
<!--[if IE]>
```

To this

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
```

Hope this helps some people.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just throwing out a guess here, but have you tried putting your code into the `.ready()` handler? I'm thinking that maybe the reason why your code isn't working is that the document is not fully loaded when the code executes. So, just for kicks, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code here*/ });
```

I am able to use the datepicker control with no problems in IE7 and IE8, but my code is in the .ready handler.

I cannot attest to the functionality in lower versions of IE, but I'd suspect that IE6 would have some issues.

Comment: ` $(function() { /*your code here*/ });` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){ /*your code here*/ });`

Comment: Right - the code in the question is already in a "ready" handler.